# how to give time limit to shutdown for windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp

I want to shutdown my windows 7/xp after 30 min automatically by using shortcut,
how do i create shortcut which will ask me time limit and after that time limit it will shutdown windows 7/xp automatically.

Comment: A shortcut alone cannot do that. The shortcut needs to run a separate application that then prompts you, then keeps track of the time, and issues the shutdown when appropriate.

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic here. Operating system and general computer questions belong on [su] instead.

Comment: You can write a batch file for this, or else there are lots of GUI apps that allow you to specify the time to shutdown/sleep/logoff/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Even easier way to do it: 
Create a shortcut with the target: shutdown /s /f /t 1800

That will cause the computer to reboot after 1800 seconds, and also to force any open applications to close (WARNING: The /f switch will cause you to lose any unsaved data).  I use something similar to reboot my work laptop and servers remotely, using this same command.

Comment: You may want to to add the `/f` switch to force open applications to shutdown.  From a command prompt run `shutdown /?` to see all the switches.

Comment: @Keltari That is an excellent suggestion, I'll update my answer with that information.

Answer (score 0):

Compile this C program and and the exe file is the one that you are looking for..
if u like this select this as answer..

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
main() { 
    int hour,minutes;
    long int total;
    printf("\nEnter the no.of.hours and minutes for shuting down:");
    scanf(" %d %d",&hour,&minutes);
    total = hour*60*60 + minutes*60; 
    sleep(total);
    system("C:\\windows\\system32\\shutdown /s /t 10");
    return 0;
}
```